# Search from multiple MongoDB collections using MapReduce - Java

Tags: java, mongodb, mapreduce

I'm building a simple web application for searching people by name. I have a few collections which contain different informations about users. The application should pull out all the information about user I'm searching for.
How can I search multiple collections for that name?
I'm first at MapReduce and I would appriciate If you help me in creating this map reduce function or any other methods.

Sorry for my bad english...

Search input goes here in index.html

```
<input id="input" type="text" name="fname"> 
<input type="submit">
```

Then, I get parametres in Results.java servlet and redirect the results to other jsp page

```
String by_fname = request.getParameter("fname");

MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);
DB db = mongoClient.getDB("hospital");
DBCollection coll = db.getCollection("patients");

BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject("fname", by_fname);
DBCursor cursor = coll.find(query);

ArrayList<Users> userList = new ArrayList<Users>();

while (cursor.hasNext()) {
            DBObject event = cursor.next();
            fname = String.valueOf(event.get("fname"));
            lname = String.valueOf(event.get("lname"));

            Users user = new Users();
            user.setFname(fname);
            user.setLname(lname);

            userList.add(user);
}

request.setAttribute("userList", userList);
   request.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/s_results.jsp").forward(request,response);
```

Comment: "search multiple collections for that name?" - you have to search each collection independently. Also, map-reduce is usually for aggregations (which I believe is not your case). Do a simple find for each collection you want to pull the information from and join the information on the client side.

Comment: it's just a example. I want make it using map reduce. or any other methods for parallel searching

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't search multiple collections simultaneously without actually starting multiple searches (in a thread pool for example) and then aggregating the results within your client code. This is true of all search, update, and aggregation options for MongoDB. They all operate on a single collection.

You may want to consider storing your data in a single collection to allow a single search to be performed rather than introduce the complexity of combining multiple searches from multiple searches.

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve it through java map reduce programming. you can configure multiple input collections to a mapper.you will get clear idea by watching this link...
           https://github.com/pavanIntel/Apache-Spark-with-MongoDB